Dissect code related to "Convergent rounding: Round half to even" written in SystemVerilog
This question is related to article on rounding found here.
The "Convergent rounding: Round half to even" code is written as follows:
assign  w_convergent = i_data[(IWID-1):0]
            + { {(OWID){1'b0}},
                i_data[(IWID-OWID)],
                {(IWID-OWID-1){!i_data[(IWID-OWID)]}}};

always @(posedge i_clk)
    o_convergent <= w_convergent[(IWID-1):(IWID-OWID)];

I am not able to understand what exactly the following lines are doing and why they are required:
        + { {(OWID){1'b0}},
            i_data[(IWID-OWID)],
            {(IWID-OWID-1){!i_data[(IWID-OWID)]}}};

EDIT:
There are three things that are confusing me about this,
(1) Why is there no IF statement to accomodate the case where the input is exactly half-way e.g 1.5, 2.5 e.t.c.
(2) Why do we need the third part {(IWID-OWID-1){!i_data[(IWID-OWID)]}}, aren't these bits always supposed to be 0?
(3) Since SystemVerilog can easily add two logic vectors together when they have different size, why do we need the {(OWID){1'b0}}?

Another way to write that is:
+
    { 
        {(OWID){1'b0}}      ,
        i_data[(IWID-OWID)] ,
        {(IWID-OWID-1){!i_data[(IWID-OWID)]}}
    };

This means we are concatenating 3 expressions (separated by the 2 commas).
Assume the following constants:
parameter IWID = 16;
parameter OWID =  5;

Now let's plug in the values:
+
    { 
        {(5){1'b0}}    ,
        i_data[(16-5)] ,
        {(16-5-1){!i_data[(16-5)]}}
    };

In the term {(5){1'b0}}, the 2 sets of braces are known as the replicated concatenation operator.  This replicates the one bit (1'b0) 5 times, yeilding the 5-bit constant 5'b0_0000.  Simplifying, we have:
+
    { 
        5'b0_0000  ,
        i_data[11] ,
        {10{!i_data[11]}}
    };

Assume i_data[11] = 1'b1:
+
    { 
        5'b0_0000,
        1'b1,
        {10{1'b0}}
    };

This leaves the 16-bit value:
+
    { 
        5'b0_0000,
        1'b1,
        10'b00_0000_0000
    };


Thanks, I have update the questions with three things that are specifically confusing for me.

(1) Why is there no IF statement to accomodate the case where the input is exactly half-way e.g 1.5, 2.5 e.t.c.
(2) Why do we need the third part {(IWID-OWID-1){!i_data[(IWID-OWID)]}}, aren't these bits always supposed to be 0?
(3) Since SystemVerilog can easily add two logic vectors together when they have different size, why do we need the {(OWID){1'b0}}?

@quantum231: The original question was focused.  Instead of adding new questions into the question, I recommend accepting this answer, then posting a new question.  For the new question, I recommend running simulations, then asking a specific qustion if there is something about the simulation you do not understand.

Are you able to figure out how this actually performs the rounding operation? I thought that we need to look at the bit just after decimal point (or the one just after OWID) but this code does not do that.
